# How to organize <div>s in a grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to organized 4 divs in 2 colums and 2 rows but they show up in just a column and 4 rows. I am using grid-template-areas like this ...

```css
  .table-products {
    display: flex, grid;
  }
  .grid {
  grid-template-areas:
    "header1   header2"
    "body1   body2";
  }
  .table-products__header1 {
  grid-area: header1;
  background: yellow;
  }
.table-products__body1 {
  grid-area: body1;
  background: green;
  }
.table-products__header2 {
  grid-area: header2;
  background: blue;
  }
.table-products__body2 {
  grid-area: body2;
  background: red;
  }
.table-products__header1, .table-products__header2, .table-products__body1, .table-products__body2 {
  width: 40%;
```

```html
<div class="table-products">
<div class="table-products__header1">
header1
</div>
<div class="table-products__body1">
body1
</div>
<div class="table-products__header2">
header2
</div>
<div class="table-products__body2">
body2
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the headers next to each other and the bodies just below.

Could you help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D!! I have just updated it and still no working.

Comment: you update nothing (1) your display value is wrong (2) you have no element with the .grid class

Answer (score 0):

Just set `display:grid` on the parent...

```css
  .table-products {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header1   header2" "body1   body2";
}

.table-products__header1 {
  grid-area: header1;
  background: yellow;
}

.table-products__body1 {
  grid-area: body1;
  background: green;
}

.table-products__header2 {
  grid-area: header2;
  background: blue;
}

.table-products__body2 {
  grid-area: body2;
  background: red;
}

.table-products__header1,
.table-products__header2,
.table-products__body1,
.table-products__body2 {
  width: 40%;
```

```html
<div class="table-products">
  <div class="table-products__header1">
    header1
  </div>
  <div class="table-products__body1">
    body1
  </div>
  <div class="table-products__header2">
    header2
  </div>
  <div class="table-products__body2">
    body2
  </div>
</div>
```